# Add lines using sed matching two line

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed, oracle

I have a file like below

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER_DG =
  (SID_LIST =
      (SID_DESC =
         (GLOBAL_DBNAME = DRCDBDB_DGMGRL)
         (ORACLE_HOME = /ofa/u1002/18C_DB_HOME)
         (SID_NAME = DRCDBDB1)
      )
      (SID_DESC =
         (GLOBAL_DBNAME = DRNONCDB_DGMGRL)
         (ORACLE_HOME = /ofa/u1002/18C_DB_HOME)
         (SID_NAME = DRNONCDB1)
      )
   )



SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
      (SID_DESC =
         (GLOBAL_DBNAME = DRTESTDB)
         (ORACLE_HOME = /ofa/u1002/18C_DB_HOME)
         (SID_NAME = DRTESTDB1)
      )
      (SID_DESC =
         (GLOBAL_DBNAME = DRMIGDB)
         (ORACLE_HOME = /ofa/u1002/18C_DB_HOME)
         (SID_NAME = DRMIGDB1)
      )
      (SID_DESC =
         (GLOBAL_DBNAME = DRNONCDB)
         (ORACLE_HOME = /ofa/u1002/18C_DB_HOME)
         (SID_NAME = DRNONCDB1)
      )
   )
```

I am using the command below command to add the below lines in the file. But Since I have two matching lines as same the below line is added on both.

```
sed -i '/SID_LIST =/a \ \ \ \ (SID_DESC = \n \ \ \ \ \ (GLOBAL_DBNAME = DB11G) \n \ \ \ \ \ (ORACLE_HOME = /ofa/u1002/18C_DB_HOME) \n \ \ \ \ \ (SID_NAME = DB11G1) \n \ \ \ )' /tmp/listener.ora
```

Now I need to add only after `"SID_LIST_LISTENER =  (SID_LIST ="` line

How to use sed to match two lines

Comment: I even tried like below. But it is not working  sed -i '/SID_LIST_LISTENER = SID_LIST =/a \ \ \ \ (SID_DESC = \n \ \ \ \ \ (GLOBAL_DBNAME = DB11G) \n \ \ \ \ \ (ORACLE_HOME = /ofa/u1002/18C_DB_HOME) \n \ \ \ \ \ (SID_NAME = DB11G1) \n \ \ \ )' /tmp/listener.ora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match the first line with a simple `/^...` regexp, and then use a bracketed block to examine the second line.

```
sed '/^SID_LIST_LISTENER =$/{ N ; /\n\s*(SID_LIST =$/ a _line(s) to append _
    ; }'
```

`N` reads in the next line of input, appending to the one you already have, and `/\n...` matches only at the join.  On all non-matches, the input will still be printed unmodified.

When trying to append lines with `a\`, it's probably easier to put it all into a script file:

```
/^SID_LIST_LISTENER =$/{ N ;
  /\n\s*(SID_LIST =$/ a\
    (SID_DESC =\
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = DB11G)\
      (ORACLE_HOME = /ofa/u1002/18C_DB_HOME)\
      (SID_NAME = DB11G1)\
    )
  ; }
```

and call it with

```
sed -f addlines.sed
```

Also be aware that this routine won't work if your input contains two consecutive "first lines", ie.

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
```

because the first match will "use up" the second; but I don't think that's going to occur given the structure of your input.

Comment: I tried this ans its not working                    `sed -i '/^SID_LIST_LISTENER =$/{ N ; /\n\s*(SID_LIST =$/ a \ \ \ \ (SID_DESC = \n \ \ \ \ \ (GLOBAL_DBNAME = DB11G) \n \ \ \ \ \ (ORACLE_HOME = /ofa/u1002/18C_DB_HOME) \n \ \ \ \ \ (SID_NAME = DB11G1) \n \ \ \ )' /tmp/listener.ora`

Comment: What was the error you got?  If it was `unmatched '{'`, then that's because you missed the second line (`; }'`).

Comment: Yes I tried like this and it works. But the command is two lines ... any way to do it on single line. `sed -i '/^SID_LIST_LISTENER =$/{ N ; /\n\s*(SID_LIST =$/a \ \ \ \ (SID_DESC = \n \ \ \ \ \ (GLOBAL_DBNAME = DB11G) \n \ \ \ \ \ (ORACLE_HOME = /ofa/u1002/18C_DB_HOME) \n \ \ \ \ \ (SID_NAME = DB11G1) \n \ \ \ )
; }' /tmp/listener.ora`

Comment: I don't think you can put it on a single line with standard `sed`; the `a` command appends everything up to the next line end (with the option of escaping additional linebreaks with `\ `), so you need to finish it, then close off the `}` block.  Would it be acceptable to use a sed scriptfile, `sed -i -f addlines.sed`?

Comment: that also acceptable .. I will use this method.   Thanks for the quick help

Comment: getting error `oracle:S1 sed -f /tmp/addlines.sed
sed: file /tmp/addlines.sed line 1: unterminated `s' command
`